# Using IF THEN to compare textbox value with table name

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm a newbie to VB and Access, so don't beat me up too much on this one :-P
I am trying to take a value from an unbound text box and search the database (Access 2010) for a table name that matches the value. The tricky part is that the value is entered in the text box as ABC-123. I am using the mid(Me.Text... to split the value into two parts. The ABC is a prefix that is also in a table name called ABC-Tools. This prefix changes (MTE, MOLD, MFG, etc.) depending on the required entry. But I seem to keep getting stuck at how to use in the entire function the table name. Once I get that, then I want to take it a step further and go into the table and compare the next part of the textbox entry, the 123 section which is an asset number (auto-generated primary key within the table). I have tried using the DLookup but I ran into the same problem there. FYI, this is a homegrown Calibration Management Database for a company, and this code is within a "Record Data" button on a form. All text boxes are unbound and also export their contents to a pre-formatted Excel spreadsheet for record keeping.

Here is my code so far. Maybe I am WAY off on how to properly do this. Let me know if you need more information.

```
Cat = Mid(Me.Text4.Value, 1, InStr(Me.Text4.Value, "-") - 1) 'Takes data on the left of the "-" within unbound text4 box for tool asset prefix (eg. MOLD-xxx)

AssetNum = Mid(Me.Text4.Value, InStr(Me.Text4.Value, "-") + 1) 'Takes data on the right of the "-" within unbound text4 box for tool asset number (eg. xxxx-001)

'Check database for tool

If "& Cat &-Tools" <> "{look_for_table_matching & Cat &-Tools}" Then

msg = _
  MsgBox("Tool " & Cat & "-" & AssetNum & " does not exist. Please check that the tool is in the         database and retry.", _
    vbExclamation, "")

Else {continue on with the rest of the script}

End If
```

Comment: Your If statement is comparing different string literals so the If will always be executed. I think you need use the value of the Cat variable rather than the string "Cat".

Comment: @DeanOCHow would I tell the script in the IF statement on the right of <> to look for a table with the name I am trying to compare? I keep thinking I have to do   ![Table]![tblname]    but I don't think that is it. I have been having a hard time finding out how to do that through a Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search through the list of tables in the DB:

```
Dim tdf as TableDef
Dim MatchingTable as String

For each tdf in CurrentDB.TableDefs
   If tdf.Name Like Cat & "*" Then
      MatchingTable = tdf.Name
      Exit For
   End If
Next

If MatchingTable = "" Then 'table not found
   Msgbox...
End If
```

To then search the table:

```
'Dlookup returns a null value if nothing found
str = Nz(Dlookup("<Name of field>",MatchingTable,"AssetNumber = " & AssetNum),"")

If str = "" Then 'asset num not found
   Msgbox...
End If
```

Comment: @E Mett - I get a "user-defined type not defined" error message when running the first script. It is not liking the `Dim tdf as TableDef` part. Is it not pointing to the correct place?

Comment: Oh cancel that error message issue. I changed it to `Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef` and then selected Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library in my Tools|References section.

Comment: @E Mett How would I add in the following msgbox to notify the user if the search comes up empty handed? `msg1 = _ MsgBox("Category  " & Cat & "  does not exist. Please check your entry and try again.", _ vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "") If msg1 = vbOK Then DoCmd.Close End If`

Comment: @E Mett - Thanks for the updated help. Everything works perfectly except for the DLookup when I test it with an asset number that is not within the table - such as ABC-879. `Dim Str As String
Str = Nz(DLookup("ID", MatchingTable, "ID = " & AssetNum), "")

If Str = "" Then
    msg2 = _
        MsgBox("Tool  " & Cat & "-" & AssetNum & "  does not exist. If the tool has not been entered into the database, please enter the tool into the database before entering calibration data.", _
        vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "")
        If msg2 = vbOK Then
        GoTo Early
        End If
End If`

Comment: Does the Dlookup cause an error? does it return something other than `""` when the asset number is not in the table?

Comment: @E Mett - It does not cause an error. The rest of the script keeps running as if that number exists in the table, when in reality it does not. So even when you enter a number in the text box that does not exist in the table, it acts as if the number exists and continues on.

Comment: What value does `Nz(Dlookup("<Name of field>",MatchingTable,"AssetNumber = " & AssetNum),"")` return?

Comment: @E Mett - The problem is now solved. It was not the Dlookup that was the problem. It was returning Null as it should. For some reason it didn't like how I was using the message box in the form of `msg2 = _ <rest of msg code>` I just changed it to `MsgBox("<message>")` and it works perfectly now. Thanks for all of your help!